# Delete specific item (session) from the cart - Cakephp 3.8

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cart

Friends, I have a list of products in the cart that I add for sessions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lql7n.png)

After inserting the product in the cart the result is as in the image.
I would like to delete the product. I can delete it manually.

```
$carrinho = $this->request->session();
$carrinho->delete('carrinho.0');
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
```

But I would like to do this dynamically, where the user chooses which item to exclude.

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $carrinho->index]); ?>
```

I tried to search the index and go through the parameter like that, but it is not correct. I tried var_dump ($ cart) and it also doesn't display anything.

```
 public function delete($index = null)
    {
    $carrinho = $this->request->session();
    $carrinho->delete('carrinho.$index');
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```

How can I search the index or key of the session array to delete it correctly?
I appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0):

`$carrinho->delete('carrinho.index');` will delete the thing literally called `carrinho.index` from the session. It does not reference the `$index` variable at all. What you want is `$carrinho->delete("carrinho.$index");`. Note that the quotes are changed from single to double, so that it does variable interpolation (e.g. if `$index` is 3, then this resolves to `carrinho.3`; if it was just single quotes, then it would look for the thing actually called `carrinho.$index` which of course doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attention!

tried that way, but it didn't work!

```
 public function delete($index = null)
    {
        $carrinho = $this->request->session();
        $carrinho->delete("carrinho.$index");
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```

and in index.ctp:

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $carrinho->index]); ?>
```

I debugged $carrinho and the result is in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSkZP.png)

Simply, the index value is not passed by parameter. When I inform manually everything goes well! $carrinho->delete("carrinho.0"), for example.

But when I try to receive a "carrinho$Index" doesn't work!
I debugged it $carrinho->read() for anyone who can analyze it in the image.

Thank you again!

Comment: Adding details in answers is not the way to go. Instead, edit the question with further information.

Comment: `$carrinho` here is the session *object*, not the contents of the session. What does `var_dump($carrinho->read());` give you?

Comment: Thank you, I put it in the right way!.The products on the list come correctly. Everyone in the array.

Comment: So, it's working now? If so, you should delete this answer and accept mine. If not, you should edit your question with any further details about what's still wrong.

Comment: Still does not work! So I sent the image to see if I could understand! It should work by passing the $ index variable, but it doesn't.